# With PostgreSQL how to query for records contained within a date range of the created_at field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have an invitations table with the following fields:

```
Invitations: id, created_at, completed_at (timestamp)
```

I am working to write a PostgreSQL query that returns the number of records completed between 2-7 days of the creation date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT round(count(i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '7 day' and i.completed_at > i.created_at + interval '1 day')::decimal / count(DISTINCT i.id), 2) * 100 AS "CR in D2-D7"
FROM invitations i
```

The select statement is not returning the correct value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are feeding to the first COUNT yields a boolean and never a NULL (unless its inputs are NULL).  But COUNT counts all of its non-NULL input, so whether the expression returns true or false, the count still increments.  There are many ways to fix this, a simple (but probably not the best--just the least typing difference from what you already have) one would be to use `nullif` to convert false to NULL inside the first COUNT.

But even then, is this correct?  It seems odd that one COUNT has a DISTINCT and the other does not.

So a more complete solution may be something like:

```
SELECT 
  round(
    count(distinct i.id) filter (where i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '7 day' and i.completed_at > i.created_at + interval '1 day')::decimal 
    / 
    count(DISTINCT i.id)
  ,2) * 100 AS "CR in D2-D7"
FROM invitations i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this below:

```
SELECT * from
invitations i
where 
 i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '7 day' 
and i.completed_at > i.created_at + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: Isn't that basically the same thing I have now?

Comment: No its not. You query wont compile unless you adjust it with case when. And if it was fixed, it would give you just a ratio, the proportion of rows that satisfy the date range. My query with return all the information of the rows of the rows satisfying the date range

Comment: interesting! I put this condition in my select statement and got no change in results. I need this to work in the select statement since this example is 2-7, but I'll want more like day 1 and 7+.

Comment: Can you add some sample data in your question and I will build the query to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invitations i
WHERE completed_at BETWEEN (created_at + '2 days'::interval) AND (created_at + '7 days'::interval);
```

Comment: I need this to work in the select statement since this example is 2-7, but I'll want more like day 1 and 7+.

Comment: I don't get you really well... you want the query to tell you the count between 2-7 and 1 - n? what does 1 - 7+ means? the interval is dynamic?

Comment: 2-7, meaning invitations that were completed 2-7days from when the invitation was created